# Do minimum wage laws in Europe prevent or induce immigration?

Tags: immigration, europe, minimum-wage

Do minimum wages (whether through minimum wage laws or because trade unions control access to low paying jobs) prevent or cause immigration in Europe?
On one hand high minimum wages are attractive for immigrants. On the other hand, immigrants cannot compete by offering to work for less than the natives.

I'm having a hard time getting some clarity on this issue since the theoretical and empirical arguments from different sources can be very contradictory.

And finally, the following question related to the above:
In a country with low minimum wages, would the economic elite have incentive to oppose immigration laws so they have access to cheap labor?

Comment: "On the other hand, immigrants cannot compete by offering to work for less than the natives." - but on the third hand, immigrants might be willing to work a job at minimum wage that natives might not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with putting all "immigration" in a single bucket is that it leads to all sorts of confusion about who might be affected by what incentives. Non-immigrants also tend to be completely unaware of how the system works. Each EU country has its own rules for non-EU immigrants; I'll use the [UK points-based system](https://workpermit.com/immigration/united-kingdom/uk-visa-tier-points-based-immigration-system) as a guide. (Yes, the system is already points-based, so anyone promising to "introduce a points based system" is misleading you.)

We can also see the [statistics](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/immigration-statistics-year-ending-september-2019/why-do-people-come-to-the-uk-to-work) for how many people use each kind of visa.

Tier 1: "entrepreneur" visas. Rich people only. Unlikely to be affected by minimum wage.

Tier 2: general work permits. Mostly require a specific job with an income of £30k (not affected by minimum wage), apart from some specialties which require £20k. Minimum wage is about £15k a year. The NHS is heavily dependent on recruiting nurses through this system, for example.

Tier 3 was never implemented.

Tier 4 is students. No relevance of minimum wage.

Tier 5 is temporary and youth workers. The minimum wage *might* be relevant here.

Further categories of non-visa entrants are family reunification (I don't think the minimum wage affects who people marry, and in any case there's a minimum income requirement for a spouse visa), and asylum. Asylum seekers *are not allowed to work* while their claim is being processed, may be subject to detention, and have an uphill burden of proof.

Almost none of these are "cheap" labour, except some of the tier 5 fruit pickers and other seasonal workers.

Comment: Once asylum has been granted, minimum wage likely is important. So the minimum wage might affect the choice with which country to apply for asylum.

Comment: Is it now the choice of the seeker as to which country to apply? (I honestly don't know the current rules of the EU in regards asylum)

Comment: @CGCampbell In theory, the Dublin regulations still apply. In practice, they don't. Judges in many countries don't allow sending back migrants to the first country of arrival, because those countries have so many refugees already that the living conditions aren't up to the standards the judges wish. So in practice, many refugees continue their journey inside the EU until they arrive at their preferred country. See e.g. "The jungle" in France full of refugees trying to get to the UK but refusing to apply for asylum in France itself.

Comment: @Sjoerd Gotcha. I thought that was how it is, but didn't know for sure what the aftermath of the mess was. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

- For most of the EU, **legal** immigration for labor purposes is only open to highly skilled immigrants (and of course to EU citizens, who will be subject to all the rules which affect the citizens).
- On the other hand, **illegal** immigrants would not be part of the official labor market anyway, so minimum wage would not apply to them. They are often cheated by their employer out of whatever was agreed, too.
- The way the EU is currently constructed, companies from low-wage countries can [send](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posted_Workers_Directive_1996) workers to other EU countries and pay the wages which apply in the origin country, not the destination country. (This directive has been under fire, but AFAIK it is still in force.)

Comment: Legal immigration for labour purposes is open to all EU citizens afaik.

Comment: @Jan, an EU citizen who immigrates becomes subject to the local labor laws.

Answer (score -1):

I'll assume we're talking about third-world immigrants for whom the minimum wage is relevant (not professionals like the recent immigrants from Asia).

IF the law was actually followed, definitely prevent. Their only attraction to employers is their ability to work dirt-cheap. Not having that minimum would open up opportunities while in any case they remain able to benefit from the higher wages and of more general importance, the first world conditions.

I would say that it would actually induce immigration because making domestic labor more expensive would motivate employers to use illegal immigrants.

Comment: There is still the issue of people not wanting to do the job for what employers are willing to pay and the immigrants get minimum wage because others won't do it for that much.

Comment: Let me try to interpret what you're saying. Your taking "Not having..." as an opposition to the minimum wage, when it's a neutral statement that it would reduce the inflow of immigrants (without saying that as a good or bad thing). This is what I get from how you say "There is still the issue". The point you make is immigrants wouldn't want to take jobs without the minimum wage, when immigrants aren't rejecting jobs no matter the pay. You're saying employers would still hire immigrants bc there's no competition but in any case there would be more and in any case they would hire less total

Comment: I am saying there are jobs that local people won't take regardless of the minimum wage leaving those jobs open for immigrants at the minimum (or higher) wage.